# How best can I fix my memory leak using smart pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I stumbled upon this, which looks like a memory leak:

```cpp
void method(const string param) {
    if (auto* object = createObject(param))
        use(object);
}
```

How best do I fix this memory leak?

Should I wrap the returned pointer in a unique pointer?

```cpp
void method(const string param) {
    if (auto object = std::unique_ptr<Object>(createObject(param))
        use(object.get());
}
```

or:

```cpp
void method(const string param) {
    if (std::unique_ptr<Object> object{createObject(param)})
        use(object.get());
}
```

It would be nice if C++ had type inference similar to Java's allowing something like:

```cpp
 auto object = std::unique_ptr<>(createObject())
```

or

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<> object{createObject()};
```

---

One worry I have about this is the `unique_ptr` constructor is being passed a raw pointer, so it wouldn't know how to destroy the referenced object. This is why I thought it might be better to instead *return* a unique pointer from `createObject`:

```cpp
void method(const string param) {
    if (auto object = createObject(param))
        use(object.get());
}
std::unique_ptr<Object> createObject(){ return std::make_unique<Object>(...); }
```

From what I've read, this should now successfully deconstruct no matter what the `Object` is. Is it actually bad to return use a raw pointer to construct a unique pointer? It seems the reference is clearly no longer unique.

In both situations, use requires `Object*` so I have to use `object.get()` - I don't know if this is normal.

What's the general consensus on handling this situation?

Comment: It would be easier to answer your questions with a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles `std::array createObject(){ return new std::array;}; int main() { auto* object = createObject(); }`

Comment: *Returning* a `unique_ptr` would indeed be a very good idea. That makes it very clear what the ownership semantics of the returned object are. Stay away from passing around raw pointers as much as possible, except where non-ownership-transferring views make sense, like in `use()`

Comment: Does it make sense to take `unique_ptr`s as a parameter, as opposed to just an `Object`?

Comment: Also, if I return a unique pointer, it means I can't use the object anywhere else but the scope returned to

Comment: That isn't completely true - a unique_ptr can be "moved" using std::move into a different scope. However if your object needs to be shared you will need to use shared_ptr instead (and use weak_ptr where possible). Returning a smart pointer is a better alternative - for the reasons just described it forces you to think about the scope of the object and how it will be used.

Comment: With regards to passing in a unique_ptr or not, if you std::move it, the original pointer will be invalid after the function call. If this is a problem you could pass in the object as a constant reference and simply dereference the unique_ptr when you pass it in

Comment: About [`std::unique_ptr`'s CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr#Notes): *"There is no class template argument deduction from pointer type because it is impossible to distinguish a pointer obtained from array and non-array forms of new"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid **owning** raw pointer, non-owning raw pointer are *"fine"* (caveat is that we don't know from pointer if it is owning or not).

Better would be to change

```
Object* createObject(const std::string& param) { return new Object(param); }
```

into

```
std::unique_ptr<Object> createObject(const std::string& param)
{
    return std::make_unique<Object>(param);
}
```

Then usage could indeed be similar to your proposal:

```
void use(Object*);
void method(const std::string& param)
{
    if (auto object = createObject(param))
        use(object.get());
}
```

As you check for `nullptr` for `use`, passing by reference might be more appropriate than by pointer:

```
void use(Object&);
void method(const std::string& param)
{
    if (auto object = createObject(param))
        use(*object);
}
```

Comment: Is there a lot of overhead using / moving unique pointers between scopes?

Comment: Deferencing unique pointer should be similar to deferencing regular pointer. Moving `std::unique_ptr` is mostly 2 pointers assignations (one to the owned pointer, and one to nullptr).